# Why doesn't jsonschema validate following definition from schema?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have definition as below. And it does not validate `my_field_type_1` at all. What could be the reason? I am using jsonschema's python module.

```
definitions:
  TestRouteSchema1:
    required:
    - my_field
    properties:
      my_field:
        type: object
        my_field_type_1:
          $ref: "#/definitions/MyFieldType1"
        my_field_type_2:
          $ref: "#/definitions/MyFieldType2"
```

Comment: The schema definitely isn't right, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  Can you post a couple examples of the data you are trying to validate.  At least one that should validate and one that shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must nest `my_field_type_1` and `my_field_type_1` under a new `properties` key. So something like

```
definitions:
  TestRouteSchema1:
    required:
    - my_field
    properties:
      my_field:
        type: object
        properties:
          my_field_type_1:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MyFieldType1"
          my_field_type_2:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MyFieldType2"
```

Comment: Yeah. I also found out that I need to have additional properties key. But I could not find out why? Do you know the reason?

Comment: if you define an object type then the property definitions should be under the "properties" key. This is how json schema is specified. It doesn't make a difference if you define a top-level object type or a nested object type.

Comment: Thanks but I wonder why jsonschema allows us to specify schema in wrong way. In my opinion, it should throw some validation error for my schema.

Comment: This decision has been made by the schema spec authors to let further metadata be defined in the same schema document used by other tools. Eg. folks may build their own tooling for automatic UI generation, which is based on json schema, but also needs some further metadata.
(edit: I don't say it is necessarily a right approach)